# Mutation in pre-mRNA sequence

Tags: rna, mutations, mrna

Has there any mutations been recorded which cause harmful effects due to change in the part of pre-mRNA responsible for proper m-RNA splicing ?

Comment: Do you mean mutations in donor and acceptor splice sites?

Comment: Adding to Alans question: Mutation of the pre-mRNA only (due to mistakes during transcription) or mutations in the genomic DNA which are then transcribed into the pre-mRNA and which affect splice acceptor sites?

Comment: @chris I mean mutations in the genomic dna. By the way, can we call mistakes during transcription as mutations ?

Comment: @Alan Yes, any site in the pre - mRNA involved in this.

Comment: see http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13908/what-type-of-mutation-causes-progeria

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can find mutations in the genomic DNA which affect splice acceptor sites. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_splicing) lists the following outcome:

- Mutation of a splice site resulting in loss of function of that site.
  Results in exposure of a premature stop codon, loss of an exon, or
  inclusion of an intron.
- Mutation of a splice site reducing specificity. May result in
  variation in the splice location, causing insertion or deletion of
  amino acids, or most likely, a disruption of the reading frame.
- Displacement of a splice site, leading to inclusion or exclusion of
  more RNA than expected, resulting in longer or shorter exons.

The article lists two interesting papers:

Lim KH, Ferraris L, Filloux ME, Raphael BJ, Fairbrother WG (2011). "[Using positional distribution to identify splicing elements and predict pre-mRNA processing defects in human genes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21685335)". Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 108 (27) 11093–11098.

Ward AJ, Cooper TA (2010). "[The pathobiology of splicing](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19918805)". J. Pathol. 220 (2) 152–163.

Both papers are open access.